# My IPV6 changed without restarting router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ipv6

This morning, I connected my iPhone to my home wifi; I checked IPV4 and IPV6. Everything looked OK. I used my phone for about an hour, but when I rechecked IPV4 and IPV6, IPV4 was still the same, but IPV6 was changed

1st IPV6 checked
2001:xxx:77:abcd:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa
2001:xxx:77:abcd:bbb:bbb:bbb:bbb

2nd IPV6 checked
2001:xxx:75:efgh:ccc:ccc:ccc:ccc
2001:xxx:75:efgh:ddd:ddd:ddd:ddd

Is this normal behavior of IPV6?

I didn't restart the router while I used my phone, and my wifi worked normally, with no sign of corruption.  I checked my router settings; everything is okay, and no suspicious devices joined my wifi network. -I don't turn on the router all the time; I always turn it off at night and turn it on again in the morning.

Comment: Yes; This is normal

Comment: I assume you are taking about your iPhone's IP? What is the DHCP lease time for your devices in your router's (DHCP-server's) settings?